# How can I use two counts to generate files names for each category?

Tags: c#

```
int countRad = 0;
        int countSat = 0;
        private async Task DownloadAsync(WebClient Client)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < urls.Count; i++)
            {
                stopwatch.Start();

                string extractFile = textBoxSatelliteFolder.Text + "\\extractFile.txt";
                string fNameRad = textBoxRadarFolder.Text + "\\radImage" + i + ".gif";
                string fNameSat = textBoxSatelliteFolder.Text + "\\satImage" + i + ".gif";
                if (urls[i] == "https://my.com/r/")
                {
                    await Client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(urls[i]), extractFile);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (urls[i].Contains("Radar"))
                    {
                        await Client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(urls[countRad]), fNameRad);

                        countRad++;
                    }
                    else
                    { 
                        await Client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(urls[countSat]), fNameSat);

                        countSat++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem now is the countSat start at value 0 so it will download the first urls again and the names of the countSat value start from the last countRad number.

No matter what is the order of the links in the urls List is I want to give the fNameRad names radImage0.gif radImage1.gif radImage2.gif and the fNameSat names also should be starting from satImage0.gif satImage1.gif satImage2.gif

Now the sat part downloading also radar gifs and the names starting numbers are 22,23,24....from the last radar files names numbers.

Comment: You can add `countRad++;` and `countSat++;` in first if condition also

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to give the names the counters and to keep download with the 'i' of the loop.

```
int countRad = 0;
        int countSat = 0;
        private async Task DownloadAsync(WebClient Client)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < urls.Count; i++)
            {
                stopwatch.Start();

                string extractFile = textBoxSatelliteFolder.Text + "\\extractFile.txt";
                string fNameRad = textBoxRadarFolder.Text + "\\radImage" + countRad + ".gif";
                string fNameSat = textBoxSatelliteFolder.Text + "\\satImage" + countSat + ".gif";
                if (urls[i] == "https://my.com/")
                {
                    await Client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(urls[i]), extractFile);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (urls[i].Contains("Radar"))
                    {
                        await Client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(urls[i]), fNameRad);

                        countRad++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await Client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(urls[i]), fNameSat);

                        countSat++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

1. I give the names the counters values countRad and countSat :

   string fNameRad = textBoxRadarFolder.Text + "\radImage" + countRad + ".gif";
   string fNameSat = textBoxSatelliteFolder.Text + "\satImage" + countSat + ".gif";
2. When downloading the files I don't mine the order in the List of the links I keep download the files using the FOR loop :

   await Client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(urls[i]), fNameRad);
   await Client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(urls[i]), fNameSat);
3. Increasing the counters just like before.

Next and last two tasks I want to do :

First To check each file downloaded if the downloading was fine if not try to download the specific file over and over again for N amount of times or seconds or both if for example after 5 times the download is bad don't try to download the file anymore or run timer for 10 minutes and try again.

Second To generate animated gif's for each of the downloaded images Radar and Sat. This should be easy I have my own wrapper I did from c++ to c# so I can create animated gifs with one single line for example :

```
ufw.MakeGIF(newGifs.ToList(), @"d:\satImages\mygif.gif", 10, true);
```

This will create animated gif name mygif of all the satellite images at speed 10 interval 10 and true meaning loop the animation when opening the animated gif.